# canonical url issue https://example.com/offline-plugin-app-shell-fallback/ in Gatsby.js

Tags: gatsby

I work on Gatsby Project in which I faced a canonical URL issue, it saw always static URL like https://example.com/offline-plugin-app-shell-fallback/ , I used gatsby-plugin-canonical-urls and gatsby-plugin-offline(for PWA) plugin

**gatsby-plugin-canonical-urls**

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-canonical-urls`,
  options: {
    siteUrl: `https://example.com/`,
  },
},
```

also I try gatsby-plugin-react-helmet-canonical-urls plugin it remove /offline-plugin-app-shell-fallback/ but on page change, it saw only static URL like if I route in about us than expected canonical URL is https://example.com/aboutus but it saw only https://example.com/

**gatsby-plugin-react-helmet-canonical-urls**

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet-canonical-urls`,
  options: {
    siteUrl: `https://example.com/`,
  },
},
```

Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Most of Gatsby sites comes with a [`SEO` component](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default/blob/master/src/components/seo.js) that allows you to customize all SEO-related configuration, like the canonical. By default it looks like:

```
function Seo({ description, title, children }) {
  const { site } = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      query {
        site {
          siteMetadata {
            title
            description
            author
          }
        }
      }
    `
  )

  const metaDescription = description || site.siteMetadata.description
  const defaultTitle = site.siteMetadata?.title

  return (
    <>
      <title>{defaultTitle ? `${title} | ${defaultTitle}` : title}</title>
      <meta name="description" content={metaDescription} />
      <meta property="og:title" content={title} />
      <meta property="og:description" content={metaDescription} />
      <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
      <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
      <meta name="twitter:creator" content={site.siteMetadata?.author || ``} />
      <meta name="twitter:title" content={title} />
      <meta name="twitter:description" content={metaDescription} />
      {children}
    </>
  )
}
```

You can easily tweak it to add your canonical URL like:

```
function Seo({ canonical, description, title, children })
```

Then:

```
   <Helmet
     htmlAttributes={{ lang }}
     title={title}
     titleTemplate={overrideTitle ? `%s` : `%s | ${siteTitle}`}
     link={
       canonical
         ? [{ rel: 'canonical', key: canonical, href: canonical }]
         : []
     }
```

If you are using `PropTypes`:

```
canonical: PropTypes.string,
```

And finally, to use it, add the following snippet in each page you want to customize the SEO specs:

```
 <SEO
   title="Some title"
   description="Some desc"
   canonical="https://example.com/aboutus"
 />
```

To make it dynamic, you can use the [`location` property](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/location-data-from-props/) which is exposed by default in top-level component (pages and templates) and it looks like:

```
{
  key: 'ac3df4', // does not populate with a HashHistory!
  pathname: '/somepage',
  search: '?someurlparam=valuestring1&anotherurlparam=valuestring2',
  hash: '#about',
  state: {
    [userDefined]: true
  }
}
```

*Source: docs*

Hence, you can use `pathname` to make the URL dynamic:

```
 <SEO
   title="Some title"
   description="Some desc"
   canonical={`https://example.com/${props.location.pathname}`}
 />
```

I think it's much more clean and segregates responsibilities better than using a plugin (which adds a third-party dependency)

Comment: Great Answer Ferran. +1 But "gatsby-plugin-canonical-urls" does it nicely. It's a headache to do it manually. Isn't it?

Comment: I do not agree. It's a far way more customizable using a SEO component (it's the purpose of the component itself and a built-in method and not adding a new dependency like `gatsby-plugin-canonical-urls` does). In addition, if you add an external dependency you are attached to them and any Gatsby update may break the code, while adding a built-in solution doesn't